# Can we have null value for BIGINT column in HIVE

Tags: hive, null, bigdata

I have a question , probably a basic one . I would like to give null value to a column whose data type BIGINT . Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible and easy to check:

1. `hive> create table test_null_bigint(col bigint);`
2. `insert into table test_null_bigint values(null);`
3. `hive> select * from test_null_bigint;`

OK

**NULL**

Time taken: 21.556 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apache Hive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-HandlingofNULLValues), you should be able to simply leave the value empty.:

> Missing values are represented by the special value NULL.

Have you tried anything yet? Are you running into any issues?

Comment: I gave the empty value for the big int column and it's throwing error .

Comment: What error? Please edit your question to include what you're doing and the error message you're receiving.